# Delaunay Triangulation - Removing Triangles

Tags: matlab, triangulation, delaunay

I made a Delaunay Triangulation using Matlab version 2013. I want to remove some of the triangles, meaning canceling their connectivity, for example triangle number 760. How can I make this change? When I tried to edit the connectivity list:

```
dt.ConnectivityList(760 , :) = [];
```

I got the message:

```
Cannot assign values to the triangulation.
```

I thought about maybe copying specific fields to a different structure, but:

a. I'm not familiar with structures so I don't know how to do it right.
b. After I copy the structure, how can I get my triangles?

`dt` contains 3 fields: `Points`, `ConnectivityList` and `Constraints` (empty field).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add details of what you aldready achieve. Your question is too broad to be answered.

Comment: You should consider selecting answers for your questions that work for you. That will remove your questions from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 4):

A brief note on MATLAB objects. When you access a field for reading, you are basically doing `get(obj, fieldname);`. When you try to set a field as you are doing, you are actually calling `set(obj, fieldname, new_value)`. Objects do not necessarily allow you to do these operations.

The triangulation object is read-only, so you will have to make copies of all the fields. If, as you mentioned, you would like to make a structure with similar fields, you can do as follows:

```
dts = struct('Points', dt.Points, 'ConnectivityList', dt.ConnectivityList);
```

Now you can edit the fields.

```
dts.ConnectivityList(760) = [];
```

You may be able to plot the new structure, but the methods of the `delaunayTriangulation` class will not be available to you.

To plot the result, use `trisurf`:

```
trisurf(dts.ConnectivityList, dts.Points);
```

Comment: thanks!
now for the last question :)
say for example that dt is:
3  5   7
10 2   8
when i copy it to dts (its the ConnectivityList filed), i get:
3 10 5 2 7 8
is there any way saving the exact size and dimenssions of the original field (dt.ConnectivityList)?

Comment: `sz=size(dt.ConnectivityList)` you never really need to "save" it because the original object is always there until you clear it.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing same problem. I found another solution. Instead of creating a new struct just create an object of its super class i.e. triangulation class with edited connectivity list.
Here is my code

P- list of points

C- Constraints (optional)

```
dt=delaunayTriangulation(P,C); %created triangulation but dt won't let you change connectivity list

list=dt.ConnectivityList;
%your changes here

x=triangulation(list,dt.Points);
```

Now you can use `x` as triangulation object

```
triplot(x)
```